# ggplot2 - adding facet_grid gets the wrong groups of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code generates what it supposed to be.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=df$month,y=df$fuel_swiperate,color=trans_card_type,group=trans_card_type)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Since I have each category to be on a different facet, I am adding the facet_grid option, but the data is becoming very weird after that as the data are in the wrong facet.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=df$month,y=df$fuel_swiperate,color=trans_card_type,group=trans_card_type)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~trans_card_type)
```

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without reproducible data, but did you try with removing the argument `group=trans_card_type`?

Comment: @Phil thanks for your response. The dataset only has two columns: 1.trans_card_type (three categories) 2.month(1-12) 3.fuel_swiperate (the value)

also yea I tried. the points were not in the right facets still.

Comment: What I was asking is, did you try with the following code: `ggplot(df,aes(x=df$month,y=df$fuel_swiperate,color=trans_card_type)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~trans_card_type)`

Comment: i did. the points were not in the right facets still. and without grouping, ggplot is not able to draw the lines.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `df` and the output of `str(df)`? As I said, it's difficult to determine the issue without looking at how the data is organized.

Comment: don't use `$` in `aes`.

Comment: You have used `facet_grid(~trans_card_type)` with a one-sided formula. Please, try either `facet_wrap(~trans_card_type)` or `facet_grid(. ~ trans_card_type)`. See `?facet_wrap` and `?facet_grid` for details.